# Let's change the canonical question about forming possessives for words which end in 'z' [Completed]

Tags: discussion, duplicates, canonical-question

I voted to close the question https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/362525/when-a-name-ends-in-z as a duplicate of [Possessive form for a surname ending with "z"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/343943/possessive-form-for-a-surname-ending-with-z) (Q1).

Unfortunately, that question is in turn closed as a duplicate of an earlier question [Should an apostrophe be used with a z at the end of a word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/187031/should-an-apostrophe-be-used-with-a-z-at-the-end-of-a-word) (Q2).

I think it should be the other way around. Tchrist's  answer to Q1 is more informative with much more detail than Q2, whose answer is actually (and unhelpfully) about "proper nouns ending in s". Q1 has the *canonical* canonical answer, and I think all future questions should be closed as a dupe of it, not of Q2.

Similar to how [we nominated a new canonical](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6934/55623) "asking for an ordinal" question, can we please vote to re-open Q1, and when that's done, vote to close Q2 as a dupe of Q1?

Comment: @danbron Thank you very much for the help and edit., I voted to reopen Q1. It needs three more reopen votes.

Comment: As you probably suspect, the other reopen vote on Q1 is mine. Let's see what others think, now.

Comment: @DanBron Reopened and I voted to close the other question as duplicate.

Comment: Sounds good. Me too.

Comment: Reopening and closing are completed. Thank you all for your support.

Comment: I'm delighted to see an instance where this type of adjustment regarding which Q&A should be treated as primary and which as duplicate has occurred smoothly on the basis of a Meta request. The result genuinely (albeit modestly) improves the site. Nice work, Rathony!

Comment: @SvenYargs Actually it started with my misunderstanding and lack of experience (please read the edit history). It's all Dan Bron's work, not mine.

Comment: I see. Nice work, Dan Bron—and Rathony!